# ssh-copy-id in one line with password, possible?

Tags: ssh, freebsd, ssh-keys, ansible

I'm trying to setup an automated script in Ansible to set a new server, and i'm using `ssh-copy-id` to add the Ansible master server to the new server's authorized ssh keys.

I created a script which uses `ssh-copy-id`, but that command is asking for the new server's password.

Is it possible to give it that password in the same line of calling it so i can automate it in a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with a [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945998/enter-password-multiple-times) using [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method I use to provision new Debian hosts without known ssh keys. Host needs to have `python` and `python-apt` packages installed for this playbook to work out of the box. If you want to test it on a VM, you can run Debian installer with boot parameter `url=drybjed.github.io` - installer will download a preseed file with `python` and `python-apt` packages selected (among others). After installation, default password for root account will be `debian` and you will be forced to change it upon first login.

After installation and first login:

1. Make sure that you can ssh into the root@host using password (accept host fingerprint, etc.).
2. Create `init.yml`:

   ```
   hosts: all
     user: root
     sudo: no
     tags: init
     vars:
     - ssh_user: $ENV(USER)

     tasks:
     - name: INIT | Create admin system group
       group: name=admins system=yes state=present
       tags: init

     - name: INIT | Create admin account from current user
       user: name=$ssh_user state=present shell=/bin/bash groups=admins
       tags: init

     - name: INIT | Make sure essential software is installed
       apt: pkg=$item state=latest install_recommends=no
       with_items:
       - python
       - python-apt
       - sudo
       tags: init

     - name: INIT | Install ssh public key from current account
       authorized_key: user=$ssh_user key="$FILE(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"
       tags: init

     - name: INIT | Install sudoers file for admin accounts
       lineinfile: "dest=/etc/sudoers.d/admins state=present create=yes regexp='^%admins' line='%admins ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: SETENV: ALL' owner=root group=root mode=0440"
       tags: init
   ```
3. Run Ansible with: `ansible-playbook -k -l host init.yml`. Ansible will ask for root password, create a system `admins` group with access to sudo, create an user account based on your current user, copy your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to your new account, and add it to the `admins` group.

From now you can use Ansible through your user account using sudo.

Comment: Almost worked for me. Had to do this for the ssh key: `authorized_key: user={{ ansible_user_id }} key="{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try a dirty hack with `expect`, but that's all it is: a dirty hack.

The correct way of having a public key in a just provisioned host is to add that step to the provision itself, i.e., include it it your `pressed`, `kickstart` or custom method you use to provision you hosts.

Comment: Can you give me an example of using "expect" with "ssh-copy-id"?

Comment: Check the links in @Petter H's answer